# ToolStripMenuItem shortcut keys do not ender line with mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a strange problem. I have a toolStripMenuItem that I wish to have the first letter underlined.  This is in Windows Forms VS 2010.
It is defined in the designer with text equal to "&Expand" and show shortcut keys = true and shortcut keys = Alt+E.  It shows up in the form in designer as expected with the E underlined.
I have a click event that changes the name, and then does something.  If you click again it sets the name back

```
    private void expandToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (expandToolStripMenuItem.Text == "&Expand")
        {
            expandToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Collaps&e";
            expandToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Alt | Keys.E;
            // execute some other code
        }

        else
        {
            expandToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&Expand";
            expandToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Alt | Keys.E;
         }
    }
```

I also set the &Expand in the form shown and load events although this makes no difference.
Now when the form opens the E is not underlined.  If I click it with the mouse it shows Collapse but the e is not underlined.  I can go back and forth with the mouse and the letters are never underlined.  However if I type AltE, the letter is underlined in both cases from that point on.  Even with the mouse.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `expandToolStripMenuItem_Click` did you use the designer to automatically create this event..? or did you type it manually..if you typed it manually.. I would check the events in the designer for the MenuStrip Item and make sure that it's assigned to the proper event first..

Comment: I want to say this is expected functionality. In Visual Studio it behaves the same way. Open Notepad and click the 'File' menu, notice none of the shortcut key letters are underlined. If you press Alt+F then all the file menu items are shown with their shortcut key letters underlined.

Comment: One more note, it is probably better to put this functionality in the [DropDownOpening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownopening.aspx) event so that it is fired whether or not the drop down is opened with a click or via the parent menu item being selected via shortcut keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my comment, I looked a little deeper. This is expected functionality and is [configurable by the user](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-keyboard-shortcut-access-keys-in-windows-vista).

In the Windows Control Panel in the Ease of Access Center, there is an option in the "Make the keyboard easier to use" section called "Make it easier to use keyboard shortcuts: Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys". If that check box is unchecked the system will only underline access keys (the proper name for the shortcut underlining which you're dealing with) when the user is already navigating with access keys (using Alt). If the check box is checked then they will always be underlined.

You can test this with the file menu in pretty much any application in Windows.

Comment: Wow you are right. Seems a little shortsighted of. Net to do so no? I mean if I explicitly define it then it should show right? Thanks for all the answers. Tom

Comment: Not sure its short-sighted, it makes sense if you think about it. If I open a menu item with the mouse, I probably don't care about the access keys - I'm already using the mouse. Adding a bunch of underlines when I am obviously not using them would add unneeded clutter.